# Create dropdown in Angular like Google

Tags: angular, dropdown

I want to create dropdown like Google, when we click on our Google account pic/logo it dropdown with information like manage account or sign-out etc.

[you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKwgv.png)

Please do let me know or give me code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

your question is not very clear. You can create a dowpdown menu like this:
https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples#menu-icons
if you don't want to have a menu but a customizable overlay you can do it like this:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/examples#cdk-overlay-basic

Comment: i have attached the screenshot..

Comment: yes but it's still not very clear what you want... I guess you want an overlay. Did you looked at Material CDK Overlay as I liked above?

Comment: yes i looked, but i want html and css for above screenshot..

Comment: you cannot pretend that someone dose the work for you. The Stackoverflow community is here in order to help if you have a question or an error and not to do your job.

Comment: i have added angular material but it doesn't working, it showing me three dots of trigger menu but not drop down